# Efficient way to write a lot of lines to a text file

Tags: c#, .net, textwriter

I started off doing something as follows:

```
using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath, append))
{
    foreach (MyClassA myClassA in myClassAs)
    {
        textWriter.WriteLine(myIO.GetCharArray(myClassA));

        if (myClassA.MyClassBs != null)
            myClassA.MyClassBs.ToList()
                .ForEach(myClassB =>
                    textWriter.WriteLine(myIO.GetCharArray((myClassB)));

        if (myClassA.MyClassCs != null)
            myClassA.MyClassCs.ToList()
                .ForEach(myClassC =>
                    textWriter.WriteLine(myIO.GetCharArray(myClassC)));
    }
}
```

This seemed pretty slow (~35 seconds for 35,000 lines).

Then I tried to follow the example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fyuan/archive/2012/08/04/textwriter-writeline-string-object-in-less-memory-less-time.aspx) to create a buffer, with the following code, but it didn't gain me anything.  I was still seeing times around 35 seconds.  Is there an error in how I implemented the buffer?

```
using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath, append))
{
    char[] newLineChars = Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray();
    //Chunk through 10 lines at a time.
    int bufferSize = 500 * (RECORD_SIZE + newLineChars.Count());
    char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];
    int recordLineSize = RECORD_SIZE + newLineChars.Count();
    int bufferIndex = 0;

    foreach (MyClassA myClassA in myClassAs)
    {
        IEnumerable<IMyClass> myClasses =
            new List<IMyClass> { myClassA }
                .Union(myClassA.MyClassBs)
                .Union(myClassA.MyClassCs);

        foreach (IMyClass myClass in myClasses)
        {
            Array.Copy(myIO.GetCharArray(myClass).Concat(newLineChars).ToArray(),
                0, buffer, bufferIndex, recordLineSize);

            bufferIndex += recordLineSize;

            if (bufferIndex >= bufferSize)
            {
                textWriter.Write(buffer);

                bufferIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    if (bufferIndex > 0)
        textWriter.Write(buffer);
}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried using StringBuilder and build the string then just write once to the file.

Comment: any specific reason to use buffers?

Comment: How certain are you that it's really the IO that's the problem here? What happens if you just write to a `StreamWriter` wrapped around a `MemoryStream`, for example?

Comment: Left justify the code for readability.  What is MyClassBs?

Comment: @Blam - MyClassB (as well as MyClassA and MyClassC) are typical POCOs.  MyClassA contains a list of MyClassBs and a list of MyClassCs.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @JustCode - it is based on the assumption that there is an expense attached to writing a line that is mitigated by writing more than one line at a time.  Not sure if it's an accurate assumption, but I got the idea from the article I linked.

Comment: @Sorceri - I haven't tried that.  I can give it a shot, though.

Comment: How do you know 35 seconds is "pretty slow"? Test the IO first to get some bounds? before tinkering with working c# code...

Comment: @Jon Skeet - I tried using a MemoryStream like you suggested, and it took about the same amount of time, so I think the issue must be with the GetCharArray() method.  I'm going to look into it some more.  Thanks.

Comment: Did not ask what MyClassA is.  Asked what MyClassBs is.  List?  OverservableCollection?  Enumerable?   Might be able to eliminate the ToList() call.

Comment: @Blam - MyClassBs is an IEnumerable<MyClassB>.

Comment: @Sorceri The downside of building all the lines in memory is that you have to have all the lines in memory. E.g. i wrote a data export that writes out a few billion lines. It would be a waste to cache that massive string in memory.

Comment: @IanBoyd I agree if you are producing a billion lines it would be inefficient but if you are doing a few then it would be fine.  Without know the details its hard to give the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I threw together a simple snippet that I think is a bit cleaner; but, then again, I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish. Also, I don't have any of your classes available, so I can't really do any kind of tests.

This sample does basically the same thing you have; except that it uses some generic methods, and it does all the writing in one spot.

```
string filePath = "MickeyMouse.txt";
bool append = false;
List<MyClassA> myClassAs = new List<MyClassA> { new MyClassA() };
    List<char[]> outputLines = new List<char[]>();

foreach (MyClassA myClassA in myClassAs)
{
    outputLines.Add(myIO.GetCharArray(myClassA));

    if (myClassA.MyClassBs != null)
        outputLines.AddRange(myClassA.MyClassBs.Select(myClassB => myIO.GetCharArray(myClassB)));

    if (myClassA.MyClassCs != null)
        outputLines.AddRange(myClassA.MyClassCs.Select(myClassC => myIO.GetCharArray(myClassC)));
}

var lines = outputLines.Select(line => string.Concat<char>(line));
if (append)
    File.AppendAllLines(filePath, lines);
else
    File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines);
```

**Here's the StringBuilder version:**

```
string filePath = "MickeyMouse.txt";
bool append = false;
List<MyClassA> myClassAs = new List<MyClassA> { new MyClassA() };
StringBuilder outputLines = new StringBuilder();

foreach (MyClassA myClassA in myClassAs)
{
    outputLines.Append(myIO.GetCharArray(myClassA));

    if (myClassA.MyClassBs != null)
        myClassA.MyClassBs.ForEach(myClassB=>outputLines.Append(myClassB));

    if (myClassA.MyClassCs != null)
        myClassA.MyClassCs.ForEach(myClassC => outputLines.Append(myClassC));
}

if (append)
    File.AppendAllText(filePath, outputLines.ToString());
else
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, outputLines.ToString());
```

Comment: I tried that and saw an improvement of 2 - 3 seconds, so it's better than what I had.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: As some others have said, you might try using a StringBuilder and appending the test, as opposed to using the list, then writing the StringBuilder's ToString() as a single write. I don't know how much/if that would improve it at all.

Answer (score 12):

I strongly suspect that the majority of your time is not spent in the I/O. There's no way that it should take 35 seconds to write 35,000 lines, unless those lines are *really* long.

Most likely, the majority of time is spent in the `GetCharArray` method, whatever that does.

A few suggestions:

If you really think I/O is the problem, increase the stream's buffer size. Call the [StreamWriter constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wf7ab94.aspx) that lets you specify a buffer size. For example,

```
using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath, append, Encoding.Utf8, 65536))
```

That'll perform better than the default 4K buffer size. Going higher than 64K for the buffer size is not generally useful, and can actually decrease performance.

Don't pre-buffer lines or append to a `StringBuilder`. That might give you small performance increases, but at a huge cost in complexity. The small performance boost isn't worth the maintenance nightmare.

Take advantage of `foreach`. You have this code:

```
if (myClassA.MyClassBs != null)
    myClassA.MyClassBs.ToList()
        .ForEach(myClassB =>
            textWriter.WriteLine(myIO.GetCharArray((myClassB)));
```

That has to create a concrete list from whatever `MyClassBs` collection is, and then enumerate it. Why not just enumerate the thing directly:

```
if (myClassA.MyClassBs != null)
{
    foreach (var myClassB in myClassA.MyClassBs)
    {
        textWriter.WriteLine(myIO.GetCharArray((myClassB)));
    }
}
```

That will save you the memory required by the `ToList`, and the time it takes to enumerate the collection when creating the list.

All that said, it's almost certain that your `GetCharArray` method is the thing that's taking all the time. If you really want to speed up your program, look there. Trying to optimize writing to the `StreamWriter` is a waste of time. You're not going to get significant performance increases there.

Comment: You should probably avoid using [.ForEach() anyway](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use buffered stream for writing

e.g. for buffered writing to Console use

```
TextWriter w = new StreamWriter(new BufferedStream(Console.OpenStandardOutput()));
    w.WriteLine("Your text here");
```

similarly for buffered writing to file use

```
TextWriter w = new StreamWriter(new BufferedStream(new FileStream("myFilePath.txt", FileMode.Create)));
w.WriteLine("Your text here");
```